# RESTful Commit to Github file

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, github

I've been looking for quite some time if it is even possible to do this.

I'd like to make a RESTful POST call with a javascript without the use of a server (node) to send a json object in the request body to update a json file in a github repo triggering a commit/push.

Comment: Have you tried? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: I don't really know where to begin, im using postman to get data back from the repo just fine, but i dont see any way to send a post and an object

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file - when i try to do this i get `{
    "message": "Not Found",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/"
}` as the response.

Comment: You're pointing at a repository that already exists? You have properly authenticated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do this using the Github API.

The URL must be something like that:
`https://api.github.com/repos/{repositoryName}/contents/{path}`

`repositoryName` is the repository where you want to put your file and `path` its path within this repository.

Regarding the authentication, you need to follow this link https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication. I successfully tested with basic auth.

You need then to use an HTTP method `PUT` with content with the following structure:

```
{
  "message": "a commit message",
  "content": "bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM="
}
```

The field `content` corresponds to the content of your file encoded with base 64.

Hope it helps.
Thierry

Comment: Is there a way to encode data with native javascript?

Comment: I think that this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript...